# Tile Map spawning within unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am designing a game within unity which will allow me to use text files to store a string of numbers which relate to a certain tile within the world. 
The file should read as shown:

```
    114122-
    100002-
    071092-
    111111
```

Each number should spawn a certain tile within a game world and a "-" splits the file where the tiles should go below the previously spawned tiles.
I have so far only looked into producing this through pseudo code and failed at most attempts within doing this within the unity scripting engine. 
This is what I have as my pseudo code:

```
METHOD BuildWorld(tilemap)
        FOR item in tilemap THEN
            FOR character in item THEN
                SWITCH (character)
                    CASE "0"
                    SPAWN an empty space
                    END CASE

                    CASE "1" 
                    SPAWN a brick tile
                    END CASE

                    CASE "2"
                    SPAWN a broken brick tile
                    END CASE

                    CASE "3"
                    SPAWN a brick with a red door
                    END CASE

                    CASE "5"
                    SPAWN a brick with a blue door
                    END CASE

                    CASE "6"
                    SPAWN a brick with a green door
                    END CASE

                    CASE "7"
                    SPAWN red key
                    END CASE

                    CASE "8"
                    SPAWN blue key
                    END CASE

                    CASE "9"
                    SPAWN green key
                    END CASE

                    CASE "*"
                    SET WorldSpawnLocation[0] = character // x value
                    SET WorldSpawnLocation[1] = item // y value
                END SWITCH 
            END FOR
        END FOR
```

I am unsure on how to go about this and any help is appreciated.

**Sorry if my pseudo-code is not set out in the best way**

Comment: so basically you're asking "how do i convert my algorithm into working code (for unity)"

Comment: not particularly. I don't want to particularly be told how to do it. I'm just unsure how I would be able to link this to a tile palette within the unity IDE. I've done some searching around and I've not come out with anything. I'm more interested in the method of linking my script to this as such rather than the solution. Sorry if it came across wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) how to load your tile palettes**

assuming you want these tile palettes to be easily added in your final build and having them loaded at runtime, you'll need to put them in your resource folder (Assets/Resources/YourTilePalettes/Palette1.txt)

**2) how to instantiate your tiles**

Then you'll need to read that palette at some place in your code, where ever you decide to create the tiles, and what palette to use for it.
Parsing your text file to separate lines by the "-" character...
And then instantiate your predefined tile structure, be it a UI image, or a quad in a 3D world, or a sprite in a 2D or 3D world...

**3) how to represent your tile palettes**

I would suggest you use JSON for your palettes instead of this text format, that would look like:

```
{
    "paletteLines" :
    [
        "paletteColumns" :
        [
            "emptySpace",
            "brokenBrick",
            "redDoorBrick",
            ... etc
        ],
        ... etc
    ]
}
```

and then you could have a corresponding model class into which you deserialise your son, with the corresponding attribute names, and you could also use an enum deserialisation parser.

**4) Willing to help you more if you do your homework and start somewhere**

Literally the only thing your pseudo code tells us is how you'd like to semantically and syntactically represent the tile palettes.

For now your question is very general "how to approach this, what are the possible sets of steps", and "without knowing even one set of steps, which ever I would chose to use, what would be the possible ways for performing each step in the set". This grows exponentially  the content a good answer would have. You question should be concise.

Ways to syntactically represent your tile palettes, ways to load them into your app, ways to instantiate tiles in your 3D world,

Each of those three have many possible ways of doing it.